# Django: Remove packages that are no longer needed from requirements.txt

Tags: django, git, pip

I just finished my first Django project and wanted to add a requirements.txt. When I type `pip freeze` I get all the packages in the venv, even the ones I didn't include in my last git commit. How do I get only the packages I used for my last commit?

Comment: If your `requirements.txt` is correct, then just create a new virtualenv and install the packages from `requirements.txt` there.

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry if my question wasn't understandable but my `requirements.txt` wasn't correct since I first created it and thought about it after finishing my project in which I tried out and discarded a lot of packages.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who has the same problem: You should always write down or delete the packages you use/ don't use anymore in a `setup.py` located in the root folder of your project. If you then delete your venv, make a new one and type `pip install -e .` it will install all the packages you currently need for your project and `pip freeze` will give you what you need for your requirements.txt.

You shouldn't (like I thought it was possible) wait till you finished your project and than type `pip freeze` since your venv still has all the packages in it that you ever tried out in it.

If you didn't know about the `setup.py` you have to delete your venv and try out which packages you need until your project runs again.